# Why is Kali Linux not starting?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I recently clicked Kali Linux on dual boot and this happens. I'm stuck here ever since pls help.
[image]

Comment: Please don't post twice the same question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400090/why-is-kali-linux-is-not-starting